# simple django tutorial, without database (hello world)

Tags: django

is there somewhere a tutorial for creating a hello world sample application with django.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the third tutorial.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view
though you have to read **up to** this point.

URL Conf:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^hello_world/$', 'dot.path.to.view.hello_world'),
)
```

View:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello_world(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world.")
```

Answer (score 2):

When I started my website I didn't have the database running at all for a while. Just leave all the database fields in settings.py blank. You can follow other tutorials for examples on how to use views, urls, templates, etc and it should work fine without the use of a database. 
However, when you get into models, forms, and user data, you will at least want to get a simple database like SQLite running.

I ran across a little factoid on a mailing list that said that a database is required in versions of django prior to 1.0 (by default anyway). But if you are new to django you probably have a version newer than that already.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [Gigantuan](http://gigantuan.net/tag/django/). A good "getting started with" video tutorials.